# Looping mutliple datasets through same function to create more datasets

Tags: r

I've got 16 datasets (named A,B,C,D etc)which I subset from for one big dataset. To save time and a memory I want to build on my function to try and do it all on one go when creating my train and test datasets which I need for further analysis.

Datesets made as below after being read in from a csv file

```
#split the dataset into a list of datasets by year
Y <- split(dat, dat$year)
#split the list into separate datasets
A <- Y[[1]]
B <- Y[[2]]
C <- Y[[3]]
D <- Y[[4]]
E <- Y[[5]]
F <- Y[[6]]
G <- Y[[7]]
H <- Y[[8]]
I <- Y[[9]]
J <- Y[[10]]
K <- Y[[11]]
L <- Y[[12]]
M <- Y[[13]]
N <- Y[[14]]
O <- Y[[15]]
P <- Y[[16]]
```

Below is my train/test dataset maker

```
train_test<-data    
set.seed(501)    
ind=sample(2,nrow(data),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))    
train=data[ind==1,]    
test=data[ind==2,]   
train_test<-data    
set.seed(501)    
ind=sample(2,nrow(data),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))    
train=data[ind==1,]    
test=data[ind==2,]
```

What I'm trying to do is something like...

```
for i = "A,B,C...
{   
train_test<-[i]    
set.seed(501)    
ind=sample(2,nrow([i]),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))    
train[i]=[i][ind==1,]    
test[i]=data[i][ind==2,]    
}
```

I've looked over stackoverflow but nothing seems to answer my question hence the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating separate datasets only to apply a function to all of them later doesn't make much sense. It's better to keep them in a list in the first place.
Your `Y` is already a list of dataframes, so we can build a function that takes a dataframe as input and split it into `test` and `train` set:

```
create_sets <- function(x){
    train_set <- sample(2, nrow(x), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)) 
    train <- x[train_set == 1, ]
    test <- x[train_set == 2, ]
    assign('x', list(train = train, test = test))
}
```

This does exactly that, using the sample method you already use, but you can use any method.
In addition with the `assign()` it insert the two sets into the original object, so we will have an easy way to refer to it within a single object.

```
Ylist <- lapply(Y, create_sets)
```

Now `Ylist` is a list of lists. Each element of `Ylist` is a year, and inside that there are two set `train` and  `test`. For example `Ylist$'2016'$test`
contains the test set for the year 2016.

Hope this works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

If your datasets are inside a named list, you can do this by iteration through the names of your list:

```
names(Y)=LETTERS[1:16]    
set.seed(501)
test=list()
train=list()
for (i in names(Y)) {
    ind=sample(2,nrow(Y[[i]]),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))    
    train[[i]]=Y[[i]][ind==1,]    
    test[[i]]=Y[[i]][ind==2,]
}
```

Still didn't check because I don't have your dataset but that should work.

Comment: Note that the first two lines inside the loop are repeated exactly the same for each iteration, so could be done before the loop for efficiency

Comment: You want to keep the seed out of the loop for sure, unless you want to cycle through different seeds.

Comment: So you should use `Y` instead of `data` and add the following line: `names(Y) = LETTERS[1:16]`

Answer (score 0):

Does something like

```
lapply(X = Y, FUN = function(x) {
 set.seed(501)    
 ind=sample(2,nrow(x),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))    
 train=x[ind==1,]    
 test=data[ind==2,]    
 })
```

work?